# jQuery hide table rows after third

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to hide all of the rows in my table after third row by using jQuery. Here is my approach:

```
<table>
    <tr id="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#duplicate'):nth-child(n+3).hide();
    alert('123');
});
```

Of course alert shows just fine so it gets executed but without any result for my table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NEVER use same `id` for each `tr`... Never. `Id` has unique name in HTML. You won't be warned but the code won't be processed correctly.

Use class instead of id.

```
 <tr class="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">5</td>
    </tr>
...
```

and Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.duplicate:gt(2)').hide();
    alert('123');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all id name must be unique. You should use classes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.duplicate:gt(2)').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

use **gt()** selector

```
 $('.duplicate').gt(2).hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't set ID for everyone, just for table :

```
<table id="duplicate">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">5</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

And change the script to :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#duplicate tr:nth-child(n+3)').hide();
    alert('123');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n59yz/)

Answer (score 1):

ok, firstly, do not use ID attribute replace ID with class...

```
<table>
    <tr class="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="duplicate">
        <td style="text-align:center;">5</td>
    </tr>
```

`$('.duplicate').gt(2).hide();`

should do the job just fine...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("table tr:first").nextAll().hide();
));
```

and set different identificators to all `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
{

    $("table tr").each(function (indx, ob)
    {

        if (indx > 2)
        {
            $(ob).hide();
        }
    })


});​
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w3yjH/